# Bootstrap div overflowing parent

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement a basic "text editor" design, in which I show some text inside a scrollable div, similar to an iframe behaviour. I need the div to always fill 95% of the viewport's height, for any viewport/device/resolution, hence the need for scroll when displaying a large body of text.

However, in my current attempt the whole page is scrolling, instead of just the grey div. The full text is correctly displayed in the white div, but the grey div should scroll vertically instead of growing: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/18086/

```
.container, body, html{
  height: 95%;
}

#dWell1 {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: grey;
}

#dText1 {
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3>
        Lorem ipsum
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="height: 95%;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card" id="dWell1">
        <div id="dText1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: like this : https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/18095/ ?

Comment: No, in that case the whole page is scrolling, instead of only scrolling the text within the grey div.

Comment: are you sure ? there is no scroll on the page, only the grey is scrolling (tested on Chrome and FF)

Comment: This is how I'm seeing it in Firefox, the page is scrolling instead of the grey div: https://imgur.com/a/8eiUzPm

Comment: I see, a FF bug I guess .. try on Chrome

Comment: You're right, it displays perfectly on Chromium, that was unexpected. However, I need this to work on FF, is there a workaround?

Comment: here is : https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/18115/ make the col also height 100%

Comment: but i suggest to follow with bootstrap ;) it may be a bug that need to be fixed

Comment: That solution works, but I'd prefer if it was the grey div scrolling instead of the white like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1e4beoy7/7/ But in this case, how can I make white div's height expand to accomodate the text?

Comment: Solved it 100% by removing the height on the white div: https://jsfiddle.net/1e4beoy7/9/ @Temani, can you please post your comments as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 100% height property on the #dText1:

```
#dText1 {
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: Same behaviour, except now the white div isn't visible until the text is loaded.

Comment: @derelict Essentially you want something like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/odjXvB am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working jsfiddle demo :-

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/18112/

```
#dWell1 {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

#dText1 {
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Works on Chromium but not on Firefox. Also, on Chromium the white div doesn't grow in height to accommodate the text.